# An exception caused due to wrong SQL query

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am working on an application which performs communication with the Sqlite database. This is java application. Although I have here a little issue regarding db communication.
This is the SQL query in order to create a relation:

```
dao.createTable(connect, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS volume.PERSON (PERSON_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC NOT NULL, LAST_NAME TEXT, FIRST_NAME TEXT, STREET TEXT, CITY TEXT);");

@Override
    public void createTable(Connection connect, String sql){
        try {
            Statement statement = connect.createStatement();            
            Boolean result = statement.execute(sql);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The following line `(Boolean result = statement.execute(sql);)` cause the NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.sqlite.Stmt.execute(Stmt.java:113)
    at database.ImplementationDAO.createTable(ImplementationDAO.java:25)
    at main.TestPoint.main(TestPoint.java:32)
```

There is something wrong the SQL query, but I don't get what is the problem?
Any suggestions?
Best regards

Comment: Look above the method definition.

Comment: where did you initialize variable - sql?

Comment: It seems like you aren't calling it with a String literal. The `sql` variable seems to be `null`.

Comment: Check if it's possible for `connect` to be `null`.

Comment: I pass the sql query invoking method 'createTable'. I have already checked whether connect or sql is null. There are not null.

Comment: paste the code of your createTable

Comment: @GV It's right there.

Comment: It could be that the connection has become stale and has being closed by the driver as the execution is occurring at the driver level. If all else is not null, I'd be checking the state of the connection and making sure its still open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your database connection is closed, try calling connect.isClosed() to verify.